# Any available action to add content before and after sidebar?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I am looking for inserting a function's output before sidebar's first widget, and one in the end after the last widget

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own actions using [do_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action), like this:

```
<?php do_action('before_sidebar'); // you can name it whatever you want ?>
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar('main-sidebar') ) : ?>
    <ul>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('main-sidebar'); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php do_action('after_sidebar'); ?>
```

and use [add_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) normally:

```
add_action('before_sidebar', 'before_sidebar_function');
add_action('after_sidebar', 'after_sidebar_function');
```

UPDATE:
depending on the codex you can use [wp_meta hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_meta):

> Runs when the sidebar.php template file calls the wp_meta function, to
>   allow the plugin to insert content into the sidebar.

but it should be added by theme authors.

This page might be helpful [Full Action Hooks Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Comment: k so that means there isn't an already made action for it.  i am working on a plugin this might not work as the user wud have to add the sidebar name or add it before sidebar.. etc.

Comment: If there was sidebar actions they should be on the action reference page on the codex.

Comment: i already went through it, can't find anything like what i need and stated above. i am actually making my 1st plugin.. so new to this. as i see a way around is i would need to register a widget with required function in ti ? and the user wud need to add it from widgets area right ? or is there a way around?

Comment: yes widgets will do the job, it's not a big deal if the user will have to activate the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Put your function, and anything else you want, before and after the dynamic_sidebar function. For example.

```
<?php if(function_exists ('my_function')) {
    my_function();
} ?>

<p>This is above the first widget.</p>

<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>

<?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>

<?php if(function_exists ('my_second_function')) {
    my_second_function();
} ?>

<div>
<p><a href="http://www.agreatsite.com">Blog Link</a></p>
</div>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar

Put the function inside a plugin, or even easier, inside your theme's functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that may not yield the results you are looking for, but it's something.

[Hooking a function onto the sidebar?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/hooking-a-function-onto-the-sidebar)